# Adding a custom front page in a dblatex-generated PDF

Tags: book-design

Is there a way to create a custom front page in LaTeX, and pass that as input to dblatex so that it uses that instead of its `\maketitle` (or whatever it generates the front page with)? I can pass it a `.sty` file, but as far as I can tell I cannot actually include an actual page in there, only various declarations.

I am moving some manuals we have written in LaTeX to Asciidoc, using Asciidoctor to generate DocBook to generate PDFs with dblatex, as this by far produces the best output of the different chains I have tested. But I would like to add a custom front page to the manuals (I can copy the LaTeX code from the current manual set for that).

I am considering creating two separate PDFs, running **pdfjam** to join them afterwards, but it would be nice to not have to go through that extra step.